# Questions about Bochner integral

Tags: functional-analysis

I was wondering

1. If there is distinction between
   existence of Bochner integral and
   [Bochner integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral#Definition), or the two always mean the same?
2. If in Bochner integral, the
   integrand is assumed to be
   measurable wrt the Borel
   $\sigma$-algebra of the codomain
   Banach space?
3. if [differentiation under integral
   sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) is still true for [Bochner
   integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral)? What is the condition
   for that to be true? What kinds of
   derivatives are involved above,
   Fréchet derivative, the Gâteaux
   derivative, or something else?

   For example,  $\frac{d}{dt} \int_a^t
       f(t) g(x,t) dt$, where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g: B \times
       \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $B$ is a Banach space,
   and the Bochner integral exists.

Thanks and regards! Also are there some nice references?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

About 3. we have something even better! Hille's theorem.

[https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/~neerven/publications/notes/ISEM.pdf](https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/%7Eneerven/publications/notes/ISEM.pdf) Theorem 1.19

> **Theorem 1.19 (Hille).** Let $f : A \to E$ be $\mu$-Bochner integrable and let $T$
> be a closed linear operator with domain $D(T)$ in $E$ taking values in a Banach
> space $F$ . Assume that $f$ takes its values in $D(T)$ $\mu$-almost everywhere and the $\mu$-almost everywhere deﬁned function $T f : A \to F$ is $\mu$-Bochner integrable.
> Then
> $$T \int_A f \, d\mu = \int_A T f \, d\mu \,.$$

A lovely theorem. Your other questions can be answered by the first chapter of the refered document.

Comment: This looks like a really nice set of notes. What is ISEM?

Comment: @Theo **I** nternet **Sem** inar. http://fa.its.tudelft.nl/isemwiki/moin.cgi/TitlePage

Comment: @Theo: Internet Seminar as Willie says. Every year there is an internet seminar where you get lectures via internet in the first phase about something related to evolution equations, in the second phase there is a project with other participants and in the last phase there is a workshop in Blaubeuren. The ISEMs of this year and next year seem a bit boring to me... But they had nice things about SPDEs or Ergodic Theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these explanations, to both @Willie and @Jonas.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work - is there another link?

Comment: @Jeremy It's been a while since your comment, but just in case you were still interested: https://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~neerven/publications/notes/ISEM.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Anton Deitmar and coauthor(s) have recently been writing some things about this: e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1246  Presumably they give references.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral
A Bochner integrable function is almost all its values in a separable subspace, and (if the domain sigma-algebra is complete) is therefore measurable in your sense.